# Matriz de estructura c++

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos, array

Buenas, primero para ponerlos en contextos la funcion del codigo es agregar ***X*** productos de una tienda y luego si el cliente asi lo quiere agregar otra tienda con ***Y*** productos el problema ocurre cuando se va a imprimir pues las filas pueden tener diferente cantidad de columnas.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct comida{
  int cant;
  string name;
  float price;
}f;

vector <comida> food1; //Vector que guarda la estructura de productos de una tenda
vector <vector<comida>> food;//Vector hecho a base del vector anterior para añadir las diferentes tiendas

int main ()
{
  string ans,ans2;//Vectores de verificacion 
  do
  {
    do
    {
      cout << "\nIngrese nombre: ";
      cin >> f.name;
      cout << "\nIngrese cantidad: ";
      cin >> f.cant;
      cout << "\nIngrese precio: ";
      cin >> f.price;
      food1.push_back(f);//Al vector de los productos se le van agregando gracias al do while
      cout << "\nDesea seguir 0<-no otro numero si: "; 
      cin >> ans;//Pidiedo variable verificadora
    }while(ans!="0");//Verificador, en caso de que el cliente quiera seguir o no

    food.push_back(food1);//Se guarda el vector de productos en el vector de tiendas
    food1.clear();//Limpiamos en vector de productos

    cout << "\nAgregar otra tienda? 0<-no otro numero si: ";
    cin >> ans2;//Verificamos si quiere agregar otra tienda

  }while(ans2!="0");

  cout << "\nNombre\tCantidad   Precio" << endl;
  //Aqui surge el problema
  for (int i=0;i<food.size();i++)
  {
    int j=0,r=1;
    do 
    {
      if(food[i][j].name!="\0"){
        cout << food[i][j].name << "\t" << food[i][j].cant << "\t   "  << food[i][j].price << "\t" << endl;}
      else
      {
        cout << "\t";
        r=0;
      }
      j++;
    }while(r!=0);
  }
}
```

Los datos que puse en entrada son:

cafe 120 10 1 tinto 200 20 1 tren 100 2000 0 1 ponque 20 200 1 pastel 50 400
0 0

Comment: Nos pones en contexto pero no dices cuál es el problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te estás expresando mal y eso hace que aún no hayas obtenido respuestas:

> el problema ocurre cuando se va a imprimir pues las filas pueden tener diferente cantidad de columnas.

Eso que dices es totalmente erróneo. El número de columnas es **fijo** y su valor es **siempre** 3 (nombre, cantidad y precio).

El problema que tienes realmente es que cada tienda puede tener un número de artículos diferente... así que lo que realmente es variable es el número de filas (filas => eje Y, columnas => eje X).

Veamos:

```
for (int i=0;i<food.size();i++)
{
  int j=0,r=1;
  do 
  {
    if(food[i][j].name!="\0"){
      cout << food[i][j].name << "\t" << food[i][j].cant << "\t   "  << food[i][j].price << "\t" << endl;}
    else
    {
      cout << "\t";
      r=0;
    }
    j++;
  }while(r!=0);
}
```

Bien, en esta porción de código intentas volcar el listado de cada tienda en la consola... tienes `food.size()` tiendas, así que parece lógico realizar una iteración desde 0 hasta `food.size()`... ahora bien, si resulta que para cada tienda (`food[i]`) tienes un vector con la lista de artículos... ¿Por qué no creas un segundo bucle que itere dicha lista?

```
for (int i=0;i<food.size();i++)
{
  for( int j=0;<food[i].size();j++)
  {
    cout << food[i][j].name << '\t' << food[i][j].cant << '\t'  << food[i][j].price << '\n';
  }
}
```

Aunque puestos a evitar redundancia...

```
for (int i=0;i<food.size();i++)
{
  vector<comida> & lista = food[i];
  for( int j=0;<lista.size();j++)
  {
    cout << lista[j].name << '\t' << lista[j].cant << '\t'  << lista[j].price << '\n';
  }
}
```

Los contenedores de la STL se diferencian de los arrays *crudos* (`int* lista`), en que son capaces de decirte cuántos elementos contienen. Aprovecha esta característica y déjate de insertar elementos vacíos al final de la lista... es un engorro innecesario lidiar con ese último elemento.

Comment: muchas gracias @eferion con eso resolví el problema.